# Connect Context Broker with mysql

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

How to store data in mysql using OrionContext broker and Cygnus?
I installed the image: orion-PSB-image-R5.2.

But I do not know where to configure Orion.
Should I install base_centos_6 and then install ContextBroker and Cygnus?

Fiware documentation is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install Orion if your VM has been created using the orion-psb-image-R5.2 image. You can start Orion (if it doesn't started yet) using the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/contextBroker start
```

Orion documentation can be found [here](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master). In addition, you can find useful [the following introduction](http://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/fiware-managing-context-information-at-large-scale). We think that Orion documentation is rather complete and detailed, but if you find confusing is some point, please explain exactly in which one so we can improve it.